# How to name the coordinates (points) in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, coordinates

I'm designing an interface using java swing. There is a canvas for the user to draw shapes (circle, triangle, square, etc.). When the user draws a shape, I want to name each point in the shape alphabetically. I know how to get the coordinates but how do I name the points?

Comment: A, B, C, D...? I do not understand the point of your question.

Comment: Yes. Like when the user draw a triangle, I want the three points of the triangle to be named A, B, and C.

Comment: `Graphics#drawString()`?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to "name" the variable? You don't want to do this with Java. Rather you can associate a String with a Point using a Map or using an object to hold all points, shapes and letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. You use `Character.toString(char)` and use `'A'+offset` to get any char from the alphabet.

See in this small demo example, which draws polygons.

- Single click creates vertices of your polygon
- Double-click stores the current polygon and starts creating a new polygon
- Right-click clears the current polygon and starts a new one.

Side-note: positioning of the text is not smart, so it overlaps lines of the polygon sometimes.

[image: Demo]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestNaming {

    private static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 600;

    public static class Drawing extends JPanel {

        private static final Font FONT = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);

        private List<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<Polygon>();

        private Polygon currentPolygon = new Polygon();

        private MouseAdapter mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                        addPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    } else if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        createPolygon();
                    }
                } else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    clearCurrentPolygon();
                }
            }

        };

        public Drawing() {
            addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        }

        protected void addPoint(int x, int y) {
            currentPolygon.addPoint(x, y);
            repaint();
        }

        protected void clearCurrentPolygon() {
            currentPolygon = new Polygon();
            repaint();
        }

        protected void createPolygon() {
            if (currentPolygon.npoints > 2) {
                polygons.add(currentPolygon);
            }
            clearCurrentPolygon();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.setFont(FONT);
            for (Polygon polygon : polygons) {
                drawPolygon(g, polygon);
            }
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            drawPolygon(g, currentPolygon);
        }

        private void drawPolygon(Graphics g, Polygon polygon) {
            if (polygon.npoints < 3) {
                if (polygon.npoints == 1) {
                    g.fillOval(polygon.xpoints[0] - 2, polygon.ypoints[0] - 2, 4, 4);
                    drawNthPoint(g, polygon, 0);
                } else if (polygon.npoints == 2) {
                    g.drawLine(polygon.xpoints[0], polygon.ypoints[0], polygon.xpoints[1], polygon.ypoints[1]);
                    drawNthPoint(g, polygon, 0);
                    drawNthPoint(g, polygon, 1);
                }
            } else {
                g.drawPolygon(polygon);
                for (int i = 0; i < polygon.npoints; i++) {
                    drawNthPoint(g, polygon, i);
                }
            }
        }

        private void drawNthPoint(Graphics g, Polygon polygon, int nth) {
            // Only works 26 times!
            String name = Character.toString((char) ('A' + nth));
            int x = polygon.xpoints[nth];
            int height = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
            int y = polygon.ypoints[nth] < height ? polygon.ypoints[nth] + height : polygon.ypoints[nth];
            g.drawString(name, x, y);
        }

    }

    protected static void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Drawing());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But is there a way to make the positioning of the text better? Or there is no possible way?

Comment: @csstudent Of course it is possible. You will need to take into account the two edges that make the vertex and compute where it is the most appropriate to position your text. You can get the bounds of the string by using `Rectangle2D stringBounds = g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(name, g);`

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to **label** the coordinates alphabetically (like A, B, C, D)

Since you said you know the coordinates already...use a `JLabel`:

```
JLabel A_label = new JLabel("A");
JLabel B_label = new JLabel("B");

A_label.setLocation(shape1_x, shape1_y);
B_label.setLocation(shape2_x, shape2_y);
```