# Java painter program drawing shapes

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, shapes

I have  a problem in this java code.
I want to make a painter program but whenever I choose a shape and draw it 
all the shapes that were drawn before become the same as this shape. Here's the code.
I know that the problem is from the for statement in the `paintComponent` but what can I replace it with?

```
class inner extends JPanel implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{
        private int oldx,oldy,newx,newy;
        private Point point1,point2;
        private Shape newRec,line1;
        Rectangle currRec;
        private Vector shape;
        private boolean status,status1;
        private int count=0;
        private Object line;
        inner(){
            point1=point2=new Point(0,0);
            shape = new Vector();
            addMouseListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {

            point2=event.getPoint();
            newx = point2.x;
            newy = point2.y;
            if(Universal==7){
            line = new Object(oldx,oldy,newx,newy);
            status = true;
            repaint();
            }


            currRec = new Rectangle(Math.min(point1.x,point2.x),Math.min(point1.y,point2.y),Math.abs(point1.x-point2.x),Math.abs(point1.y-point2.y));   
            status = true;
            repaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}                
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}


        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {

            point1=event.getPoint();
            oldx=event.getX();
            oldy=event.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {

            point2=event.getPoint();
            newx=event.getX();
            newy=event.getY();
            //count++;


        if(Universal==7){
                line1 = new Shape(point1.x,point1.y,point2.x,point2.y);
                shape.add(line1);
                //Graphics g = getGraphics();
                //g.setColor(colour);
                //g.drawLine(point1.x,point1.y,point2.x,point2.y);

                count++;
                repaint();
            }
        else if(Universal==1||Universal==2||Universal==3||Universal==4||Universal==5||Universal==6){
                newRec = new Shape(Math.min(point1.x,point2.x),Math.min(point1.y,point2.y),Math.abs(point1.x-point2.x),Math.abs(point1.y-point2.y));
                shape.add(newRec);
                count++;
                repaint();  
            }
        }

    ///// the problem is in here    
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Shape c;
            g.setColor(colour);
            for(int i=0;i<shape.size();i++){
                c = (Shape) shape.get(i);

            if(Universal==1){

                g.drawRect(c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h);
                if(status){
                    g.drawRect(currRec.x, currRec.y, currRec.width, currRec.height);
                }
            }

            if(Universal==2){
                g.fillRect(c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h);

                if(status){
                    g.fillRect(currRec.x, currRec.y, currRec.width, currRec.height);

                }
            }

            if(Universal==3){
                g.drawRoundRect(c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h, c.w/4, c.h/4);

                if(status){
                    g.drawRoundRect(currRec.x, currRec.y, currRec.width, currRec.height,currRec.width/4,currRec.height/4);

                }
            }

            if(Universal==4){
                g.fillRoundRect(c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h, c.w/4, c.h/4);

                if(status){
                    g.fillRoundRect(currRec.x, currRec.y, currRec.width, currRec.height,currRec.width/4,currRec.height/4);

                }
            }

                if(Universal==5){

                    g.drawOval(c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h);

                    if(status){
                        g.drawOval(currRec.x, currRec.y, currRec.width, currRec.height);
                    }
                }

                if(Universal==6){

                    g.fillOval(c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h);

                    if(status){
                        g.fillOval(currRec.x, currRec.y, currRec.width, currRec.height);
                    }
                }

                if(Universal==7){

                    g.drawLine(c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h);

                    if(status){
                        g.drawLine(line1.x, line1.y, line1.w,line1.h);
                    }
                }

                if(Universal==8){
                    shape.clear();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You may want take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16246610/928711) which draws only polygons but it wouldn't be complicated to adapt it to draw other shapes

Answer (score 1):

`Universal` is only ever going to be a given value at any given time.

Paints are not accumulative, they are destructive.

That is, each time `paintComponent` is called, all the previous contents is removed/wiped clean and you are expected to "repaint" the contents.

Instead of relying on a single flag, you should add the `Shape`s to some kind of `List` and redraw them all when ever `paintComponent` is called.  Equally, you could simply add the "type" (`int`) to a `List` and process that list on each repaint

Take a look at [Painting in AWT in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for an explanation of the paint process

Answer (score 1):

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two different ways to do this:

1. Add shapes to a List and then repaint all the Shapes from the list every time paintComponent() is invoked.
2. Draw Shapes to a BufferedImage and then just repaint the image ever time paintComponent() is invoked.

Neither example does exactly what you want, it only shows you the approach.